# Order of Phylogenetic nodes

Tags: r, plot, phylogeny

I am making some plots in R using a linguistic phylogeny. I want to plot a row of squares after the terminal node of the phylogeny and colour them to represent a number of variables.

I have created the squares, however I am having trouble colouring them in the correct order.

The 'phylo' object orders the node labels alphabetically, however they are not plotted alphabetically. Is there a way to get the order of the tip labels in the order that they are plotted on the phylogeny (either top to bottom or bottom to top)?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Hi, can you share some code, packages used or produce a minimum working example, thanks

Comment: Hi, I have been looking for a phylogeny which has the same make-up as the one I am using. I am not able to share my exact data unfortunately. Since looking I have found that my phylogeny may be in an unusual formatt - so it may take me some time to organise a working example. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the phylogeny to file and read it in again, the tip labels should be reset and will be in the order they appear when plotted.